# Angular - How to delete data from Firebase DB

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete specific values from my firebase DB.
I want to delete this entry from firebase:

[image]

What I tried so far is my button on how to trigger the delete button:

```
 <div class="single-bfunctions" 
 *ngFor='let bfunc of liste'>
<b> Name: </b>{{bfunc.Name}} <br>
<b> Beschreibung: </b>  {{bfunc.Descr}}<br>
<b> Key: </b>   {{bfunc.$key}}
<button type="button"  ng-click="deleteSth(bfunc.name)">Delete Item </button>
</div>
```

... and my delete-method:

```
deleteSth(name){
  firebase.database().ref('/BFunctions/').child(name).remove();
}
```

As I am also pretty new to Angular I don't really what the solution could be.
I appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your button initialisation should look like this, becuase your bfunc.Key is not defined. As is see your bfunc.Name is your key in your database. If this is like that you can make your code as follow:

```
<button type="button"  ng-click="deleteSth(bfunc.$key=bfunc.Name)">Delete Item
```

than just use:

```
deleteSth(key){
    firebase.database().ref().child('/BFunctions/'+key+'/').remove();
}
```

:)

Comment: Oh man thanks a lot you're Genius i was sitting all day in Front of this Problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ref object

```
    <div class="single-bfunctions" 
*ngFor='let bfunc of liste'>
<b> Name: </b>{{bfunc.Name}} <br>
<b> Beschreibung: </b>  {{bfunc.Descr}}<br>
<b> Key: </b>   {{bfunc.$key}}
<button type="button"  ng-click="deleteSth(bfunc.$key)">Delete Item 
</button>
</div>
```

and

```
deleteSth(key){
    firebase.database().ref('/BFunctions/' + key).remove();
}
```

If that doesnt work check your console it could be related to permissions or something else

Comment: how should I add the `$key`? just like this?
`firebase.database().ref('/BFunctions/'+$key).remove();`

Comment: change to `ng-click="deleteSth(bfunc.$key)` and change this line to `firebase.database().ref('/BFunctions/' + name).remove();`

Comment: hm no didnt work. somehow the key cannot be recognized by the delete button because I am trying to log the key like `console.log(key);` and I am getting in the console _undefined_
Do you know what's wrong?